# How can I connect to a Windows (7) running in VirtualBox from the network with RDP?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, remote-desktop

I have a Windows7 guest running in a VirtualBox hosted by Precise (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). In the settings of the virtual machine I have activated the 'Remote Display' (Enable Server) with default settings (server port, authentication method). The network of the guest is attached to NAT.

1. I try to use Remmina to connect from the host to the guest. I tried 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, the internal IP of Win7 (10. ...). Did not work so far. Do I have to active something and what on Win7 (home premium)?
2. I would like to connect to the Win7 remote desktop from the local network. Can I stay in NAT mode (preferred due to our network policy), or do I have to go for 'bridged'?

Thanks!

Comment: I know that there are a couple similarly sounding questions (and answers) around. However, I could not find one to solve my question.

Answer (score 1):

here 127.0.0.1 will not connect your virtual guest system. Apply Bridge and find guest's Ip address ( windows 7 ip address) by ipconfig or network settings. Then after try that ip to connect using Remmina.It will 100% work.

Comment: Which version of Win7 are you using? I've read that Remote Desktop is only possible to Professional and Business. Or is the remote desktop provided by VirtualBox independent from what Windows is providing?

Comment: You can access Win 7 home premium (all adddtions ) Guest from  Ubuntu host. Windows 7 Home premium is not able to access take remote of other host.